# Tomcat 8.5 is inaccessible in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

Tomcat 8.5 started with port:9090,

```
dev_hng@hng-instance-2:~$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Network status,

```
dev_hng@hng-instance-2:~$ netstat -a | grep 9090
tcp        3      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        1      0 hng-instance-2:9090     101.60.2.250:6788       CLOSE_WAIT
```

Firewall is disabled. 
Not able to access internally also, neither gives an error.

```
dev_hng@hng-instance-2:/opt/tomcat/bin$ sudo wget http://localhost:9090
--2017-04-03 18:17:14--  http://localhost:9090/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:9090... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"` in `setenv.sh` It's working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

check if tomcat recives the request at `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/localhost.<today's date>.log`

and if you have errors in `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: I had to add 
" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" in setenv.sh

It's working properly now.